# C: Parsing through an input file in order to check formatting

Tags: c

My goal here is to read through a text file that has to follow these formatting regulations:

1. No spaces/tabs between characters
2. Characters must be either non-negative integer or new line character (no letters/symbols)
3. I can only use functions given in stdlib.h and stdio.h

I am thinking of reading through the file character by character using the `fgetc()` function, but I can't think of a way that tests whether or not the character is a new line character (isn't a new line char `/n`, which would be two chars together which would ruin the idea of going char by char?).

Following this train of thought I was thinking that using `getline()`, which would negate the necessity of checking if a char is a new line character, would be easier (am I right in thinking this or would this not negate such a requirement?). Yet if I were to do this what would be the easiest way to traverse through the char string that this would produce in order to still check each individual character?

Also, if someone could think of an easier route as to checking for the format of a file using the given libraries that would be much appreciated.

Comment: if (`c` == '\n') tests for newline

Comment: Good to know - definitely going the route of fgetc() now. Thanks

Comment: Yes, but its slower to read a single character at a time instead of an entire buffer all at once.

Comment: Given the constraints, you only need to check that you get a digit or a newline.  Remember that `fgetc()` and its relatives return an `int`, not a `char`.  Normally, you'd use functions from `<ctype.h>` (such as `isdigit()`), but it is easy enough to work around the fact that you're not allowed to use them.

Comment: @stackptr: don't forget that standard I/O buffers input, so that it reads as much as possible.  The speed difference is normally quite small.

Answer (score 0):

If you use getline it will retain the newline character so you'll still have to check for it.

If you can use any of the standard C library then you can use isdigit(...) from ctypes.h

It returns non-zero if the input character is a digit.

If you use the getline function the input would be written into the buffer that you pass as the first argument.  It will append a null terminal character to this buffer so you can walk through it as so:

```
for(char* s = buffer; *s; s++)
    /* test *s */
```